# Integer argument expected int got float in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have displayed the code below, but when I try to execute it, get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/decentmakeover2/Code/cv.py", line 22, in <module>
    img = cv2.circle(img,center, radius, (0,255, 0), 2)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Im not exactly sure what the problem is, in the `minEnclosingCircle` the values have been converted to `int`, but i still get the same error, any ideas on what might be the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from scipy import ndimage

img = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.imread('img.jpeg'))
ret, thresh  = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, heir = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    x, y , w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    rect  = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box  = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0 , (0, 0, 255), 3)

    (x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    center = (int(x), int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    img = cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (0,255, 0), 2)

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)   
cv2.imshow('contours',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: Please correct your Python code format !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as follows you do not need to use return value of cv2.circle.

```
cv2.circle(img,center, radius, (0,255, 0), 2)
```

Comment: This doesn't remove error as error is due to float input arguments which should be integers. So, I think not exact solution of your error.

Answer (score 9):

This answer is probably too late, but I found that cv2.circle only can accept centre coordinates precision up to float32. If the coordinates are in float64, it will throw this error. Simple solution is always converting centre coordinates to numpy.float32.

Answer (score 3):

I have done small changes to your code for conversion of float numbers to integers. It is running without errors now. Check this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
from scipy import ndimage

img = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.imread('img.jpeg'))
ret, thresh  = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(img.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, heir = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
    x, y ,w ,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    rect  = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box  = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0 , (0, 0, 255), 3)

    (x,y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    x = np.round(x).astype("int")
    y = np.round(y).astype("int")
    center = (x,y)
    radius = np.round(radius).astype("int")
    cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (0,255, 0), 2)

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)   
cv2.imshow('contours',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I wanted exact floats as centres. Casting to int is not precise enough for me.