# Why doesn't cv2.rectangle() support float values?

Tags: opencv, bounding-box, python

I've got some coordinates of the region of interest for object detection, i got them from a model, and i want to draw the bounding box using these coordinates: 
(x,y) :coordinates of the vertex at the top left
(x+w,y+h): coordinates of the vertex at the lower right, but when i give these parameters to cv2.rectalgle(), it says that it needs int values, and i need to draw the exact values not the int ones.

Comment: Is there really a "i need to draw the exact values not the int ones" requirement? I'm guessing that you're taking that too literally. Rectangles are drawn on a integral pixel grid, and object detection is probabilistic. There is no 'exact'.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I see what you mean, by exact i meant the exact given values by the model, thank you.

Comment: The model isn't giving you 'exact'. It's just doing math and failing to round to a sensible level of precision. But the answer is, `cv.rectangle` wants integers, so you'll need to round.

Comment: As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738933/, I tried converting my floats to `np.float32` and it works!