# cv2.rectangle() TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I am writing a deep learning code that needs to detect very tiny faces. I found an implementation of [tiny face detects paper](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/finding-tiny-faces) in [Github](https://github.com/cydonia999/Tiny_Faces_in_Tensorflow) using TensorFlow. The code have to draw rectangles around faces in the image but the open cv cv2.rectangle() function giving **TypeError**. But I couldn't figure out exactly what is this error, searched the whole net found one or two issues talking about the argument being float is the problem.

**This is my code to draw a rectangle in the given image:**

```
    def overlay_bounding_boxes(raw_img, refined_bboxes, lw):

    """Overlay bounding boxes of face on images.
    Args:
      raw_img:
        A target image.
      refined_bboxes:
        Bounding boxes of detected faces.
      lw: 
        The line width of bounding boxes. If zero specified,
        this is determined based on the confidence of each detection.
    Returns:
      None.
  """
    # Overlay bounding boxes on an image with the color based on the confidence.
    for r in refined_bboxes:
        _score = expit(r[4])
        cm_idx = int(np.ceil(_score * 255))
        rect_color = [int(np.ceil(x * 255)) for x in util.cm_data[cm_idx]]  # parula
        _lw = lw
        if lw == 0:  # line width of each bounding box is adaptively determined.
            bw, bh = r[2] - r[0] + 1, r[3] - r[0] + 1
            _lw = 1 if min(bw, bh) <= 20 else max(2, min(3, min(bh / 20, bw / 20)))
            _lw = int(np.ceil(_lw * _score))

        _r = [int(x) for x in r[:4]]

        cv2.rectangle(raw_img, (_r[0], _r[1]), _r[2], _r[3]), rect_color, int(_lw))
```

**The error it's giving is:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "D:/PYTHON PROJECTS/Digital Attendance System (knn)/Tiny_Faces_in_Tensorflow-master/tiny_face_eval.py", line 242, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/PYTHON PROJECTS/Digital Attendance System (knn)/Tiny_Faces_in_Tensorflow-master/tiny_face_eval.py", line 235, in main
    evaluate(
  File "D:/PYTHON PROJECTS/Digital Attendance System (knn)/Tiny_Faces_in_Tensorflow-master/tiny_face_eval.py", line 200, in evaluate
    overlay_bounding_boxes(raw_img, refined_bboxes, lw)
  File "D:/PYTHON PROJECTS/Digital Attendance System (knn)/Tiny_Faces_in_Tensorflow-master/tiny_face_eval.py", line 62, in overlay_bounding_boxes
    cv2.rectangle(raw_img, (_r[0], _r[1]), (_r[2],_r[3]), rect_color, _lw)
TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I checked every argument data type which is integer obviously as the solutions I've found issued by others that one of the arguments being float is the problem.

What is the actual problem here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Incorrect error message for non-integer points in rectangle draw function: TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15465) Most likely, `_lw` is no integer for `lw != 0`, cf. your `if` statement. At least, that's the only argument not getting cast to `int` for every case.

Comment: @HansHirse I manually cast every value in the function by `int(value)`. It still gives me the error.

Comment: That's not reflected in your code. If you have updated it, then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67968773/edit) accordingly. `_lw = int(np.ceil(_lw * _score))` is only executed inside `if lw == 0:`. For any other `lw`, `_lw` is not guaranteed to be integer right now, since `_lw = lw` is before the said `if` statement.

Comment: I updated [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968773/cv2-rectangle-typeerror-function-takes-exactly-4-arguments-2-given?noredirect=1#comment120135484_67968773). Thank you @HansHirse

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis. You have `cv2.rectangle(raw_img, (_r[0], _r[1]), _r[2], _r[3]), rect_color, int(_lw))` and it should be `cv2.rectangle(raw_img, (_r[0], _r[1]), (_r[2], _r[3]), rect_color, int(_lw))`. That each corner point should be an (x,y) tuple. Also be sure that the x,y coordinates are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.
I checked and the problem was with the coordinates even if it cast by `int(x)`. I found another way to convert them to integer with `np.round().astype()` method.

So, i changed the for loop line to `_r = [np.round(x).astype("int") for x in r[:4]]`

That seems to solve my problem. Also, I found the solution in another [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764711/integer-argument-expected-int-got-float-in-opencv/54738933#54738933)